# Linux device driver: invalid operands to binary << (have char * and int)

Tags: c, linux-device-driver

I am trying to write a driver to read the rtc time. In the main code I have written the following. The driver side has the same definitions and ioctl handler returns the condition of flag.
On compiling the main code I get the error of "invalid operands to binary << (have 'char *' and 'int')" for the RD_RTC_TIME_UPDTD definition.
What is the reason for the error?

main.c:

```
#define RTC_MAGIC_NO        "p"
#define RTC_TIME_UPDTD_CMD 0x1F
#define RD_RTC_TIME_UPDTD _IOR(RTC_MAGIC_NO, RTC_TIME_UPDTD_CMD, int*)

int rtc_time_updtd_sts = 0;
rtcDev = open("dev/rtc0", O_RDWR);
ret = ioctl(rtcDev, RD_RTC_TIME_UPDTD, (int*)&rtc_time_updtd_sts);
```

driver: rtc.c

```
#define RTC_MAGIC_NO        "p"
#define RTC_TIME_UPDTD_CMD 0x1F
#define RD_RTC_TIME_UPDTD _IOR(RTC_MAGIC_NO, RTC_TIME_UPDTD_CMD, int*)

int rtc_do_ioctl(unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg, int kernel){
    switch(cmd) {
    case RD_RTC_TIME_UPDTD: /* Read the flag to check if the RTC time is set by system or not */
    {
        copy_to_user((int *)arg, &rtc_time_updtd, sizeof(rtc_time_updtd));
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Try to avoid repeating macros like this. It give you the opportunity to change one of them and then have to debug why two paths produce wickedly different results. Pop the suckers in a common header.

Comment: Try: `"p"` -> `'p'`

Answer (score 3):

`RTC_MAGIC_NO` implies it should be a number.  The first argument to `_IOR` should be an 8-bit number.  Instead you defined it as `"p"` which is a string literal which will give you a `char *`.  Perhaps you wanted to use `'p'` instead, which would be treated as an `int` (and should fit the 8-bit criteria).

Answer (score 1):

```
_IOR(RTC_MAGIC_NO, RTC_TIME_UPDTD_CMD, int*)
```

expands to

```
// _IOC(dir,type,nr,size)
_IOC(2U,("p"),(0x1F),((sizeof(int*))))
```

which expands to

```
    (((2U)           << _IOC_DIRSHIFT) | \
     (("p")          << _IOC_TYPESHIFT) | \
     ((0x1F)         << _IOC_NRSHIFT) | \
     ((sizeof(int*)) << _IOC_SIZESHIFT))
```

Here you try to leftshift a `char*` (the `"p"`) `_IOC_TYPESHIFT` steps. Shifting a pointer is not a supported operation in C so change `"p"` to `'p'` like the other Real Time Clock `ioctl` macros in `linux/rtc.h`.